Is there a way to evaluate whether a model is able to identify the variables that have an influence (variables generated with make_classification)?
I have a question about make_classification from scikit-learn. I have created a dataset with make_classification (binary classification task) and the aim is to test how well different models can distinguish important features from less important features.
How can I set an experiment in which I can evaluate whether a model is able to identify the variables that have an influence?
I have looked at the documentation of make_classification, but unfortunately I did not get any further.
I have set the following:
X,y = make_classification(n_samples=50000, n_features=10, n_informative=5, 
                    n_redundant=2, n_repeated=0, n_classes=2, n_clusters_per_class=2,
                          class_sep=1,
                   flip_y=0.01, weights=[0.9,0.1], shuffle=True, random_state=42)

How can I display the - in this case - 5 informative varibles? Can I shape the importance of the features when generating data with make_classification? Which features are intended to be important by make_classification? And then in a next step, I would use some freature_importance methods to verify (or not) how well a model detects the "pre-setted" feature importance/ the variables with influence.
Thank you, any ideas or advice are highly appreciated.

I'm not really sure if it's what you mean, but a lot (or maybe all?) of the classifiers in sklearn have the feature_importance method (see e.g. Random Forest Classifier. This is how much "weight" or "importance" the model gave to each feature. This is true also for regression models

Thank you for your reply. How can I display the - in this case - 5 informative varibles? Can I shape the importance of the features when generating data with make_classification? Which features are intended to be important by make_classification? And then in a next step, I would use some freature_importance methods to verify (or not) how well a model detects the "pre-setted" feature importance/ the variables with influence. Thank you for any help on this.
